# Finding the Laurent series $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z}$ about $z=i$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the function $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z}$$ and I am trying to find the Laurent series around $$z=i$$
Hence the answers need to be in terms of powers of $$(z-i)$$

So I write $\frac{1}{1+z-i+z}=\frac{1}{(1+i)+(z-i)}= \frac{1}{1+i} \left[1+\left(\frac{z-i}{1+i}\right)\right]^{-1} $ but I do not understand these steps, is there a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You're given a function and asked to find the Laurent series around a point, that is a representation
\begin{equation}
f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{k}(z-i)^{k}
\end{equation}
where $z,a_{k}\in\mathbb{C}$. Let's start with the function you're given and aim to use the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+...$ for $|z|<1$
\begin{equation}
f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z}=\frac{-1}{-1-z}=\frac{-1}{i-1-(z-i)}=\frac{-1}{i-1}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-i}{i-1}}
\end{equation}
we may now use the geometric series on the last term giving
\begin{equation}
\frac{-1}{i-1}\sum_{k\geq 1}\bigg(\frac{z-i}{i-1}\bigg)^k.
\end{equation}
This gives you a Laurent series for the open disc $|\frac{z-i}{i-1}|<1$. A slight reworking of the above method will give you the Laurent series for the rest of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Since you use the geometric series for $w=(z-i)/(i-1)$, then the series expansion works for $0<|z-i|<|i-1|=\sqrt{2}$, not for $|z|<1$

Comment: True. I'll edit the original

Comment: @michael in my notes I have $\frac{1}{1+z-i+z}=\frac{1}{(1+i)+(z-i)}$

Comment: Well I believe your notes to be incorrect as the left side of the equation does not equal the right.