# Calculate the residue of this function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

> Find the residue at $z=0$ of the function $f(z)=\frac{\cot z}{z^4}$

I know that $z_0=0$ is a pole of order $k=5$, and $$Res(f;z_0)=\frac{\phi(z_0)^{(k-1)}}{(k-1)!}$$

but I cannot get the right answer that is $-\frac{1}{45}$

Comment: Since $\cot$ has a pole of order $1$ at $0$, $f$ has a pole of order $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Laurent series approach** It is easy to see that the Laurent series of $\cot(z)$ around $z=0$ is 
$$
\cot(z)=\frac 1z - \frac z3 - \frac{z^3}{45} - \cdots 
$$
Thus 
$$
\frac{\cot(z)}{z^4}=\frac{1}{z^5} - \frac{1}{3z^3} - \frac{1}{45z} - \cdots 
$$
Hence, as pointed out in the comments the order of the pole is $5$ and indeed $Res(\cot; 0)=a_{-1}=-1/45$

**Without using Laurent Series** It is more complicated since you need to compute 4 derivates. If you insist you will need to do as follows: because the pole is of order $5$, then 
\begin{align}
Res(\cot; 0)=a_{-1}=\frac{1}{4!}\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{d^4}{dz}\left( z^5 \frac{\cot(z)}{z^4}\right) & =\frac{1}{24}\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{d^4}{dz}\left( z\cot(z)\right)\\ 
 & = \left(\frac{1}{24}\right)\left(\frac{-8}{15}\right)\\
& = -\frac{1}{45}
\end{align}
However it is a little bit messy ([click here too see why $\lim d^4(z\cot(z))=-8/15$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%28+fourth+derivative+of+xcot%28x%29+%29+as+x+to+0) ). For this case, I of course prefer the Laurent series option.

Comment: But how I can get this result without using laurent series.

Comment: @askazy I've made an edit suggesting how to approach it without  Laurent Series. Hope it helps and Good luck

Comment: It is true that by laurent series is much easier, but the problem is that I can not always remember all series.

Comment: @askazy You do not have to remember all. You can always compute them !

Comment: Using that $f(z)=f(z_0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z-z_0)^n$, or there is another way?

Comment: It depends on the case, for your case you can always use the taylor seires of $\cos$ and $\sin$ and then perform long division. Also [this question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314714/finding-the-laurent-series-fz-frac11z-about-z-i) is a typical case on computing Laurent Series.

Comment: @askazy I have add the complete computation of the residue using the derivative, of course I used wolfram to compute a part, however I supply the link on the answer. Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You do not have the rigth order for the pole, you forgot to consider the fact that $cot(z) = \dfrac{cos(z)}{sin(z)}$ has a pole of order $1$ at $z_0=0$ which implies that you only have a pole of order $5$.